# The normal loop with different styles doesn't work in search.php

Tags: theme-development, loop, search

This code in the search.php file does not work:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if( get_post_type() == 'post' ) {?>

<div id="post">
<div id="postimagen"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail', $attr ); ?></a></div>
<div id="postcontent">
<div id="categorias">
<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
echo '<li class="cat-' .$category->cat_name. '"><a href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id ).'">' . $category->cat_name . '</a></li>';}?>
</div>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
<div id="info">
<div id="informacion">Escrito por <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> el <?php the_time('d/m/Y') ?> a las <?php the_time('G:i'); ?></div>
<div id="numcoment"><?php comments_number('0 Comentarios', '1 Comentario', '% Comentarios' );?></div>
</div>
<?php the_excerpt() ?>
<div id="readmore"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Continuar</a></div>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<?php } if( get_post_type() == 'articulo' ) {?>

<div id="post">
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="postcontent2"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
<div id="postmeta">
Escrito por <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> el <?php the_time('d/m/Y') ?> a las <?php the_time('G:i'); ?>
<div id="numcoment"><?php comments_number('0 Comentarios', '1 Comentario', '% Comentarios' );?></div>
</div>
<?php the_content(false); ?>
<div id="readmore"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Continuar</a></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<?php } else; endwhile;?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: what is the result? please describe "does not work" in more detail.

Comment: Sorry, when I search something the page is blank.

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot? What PHP errors or notices do you get? Where is the rest of the template file code (what's included in the question is just the loop).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it works on my test install. I guess it depends on what you are searching for. I'm searching for 'hello' and the post 'Hello World' shows up fine.

Second, I get the following notice for this bit `the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail', $attr );`:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: attr

Third, just to be a perfectionist, I would put `elseif` instead of `if` right here:

```
<?php } if( get_post_type() == 'articulo' ) {?>
```